# How to read AWS-S3 encrypted file (AES-256 encryption) in to my IOS application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get an encrypted file from AWS S3 Bucket, and open it in my IOS application.
But i'm not sure how i can open an encrypted file in my application.
What is the steps to decrypt it?

Comment: How is it encrypted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand you're using AWS's built-in server-side encryption. In that case the data is encrypted and decrypted automatically and you don't have to worry about the decryption and key management

> Amazon S3 Server Side Encryption handles all encryption, decryption,
>   and key management in a totally transparent fashion. When you PUT an
>   object and request encryption (in an HTTP header supplied as part of
>   the PUT), we generate a unique key, encrypt your data with the key,
>   and then encrypt the key with a master key.
>
> Decryption of the encrypted data requires no effort on your part. When
>   you GET an encrypted object, we fetch and decrypt the key, and then
>   use it to decrypt your data. We also include an extra header in the
>   response to the GET to let you know that the data was stored in
>   encrypted form in Amazon S3.

Reference: [AWS Official Blog: Amazon S3 Server Side Encryption for Data at Rest](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-s3-server-side-encryption/)

It also has a nice diagram that depicts the flow.

hope this helps.

Comment: so basically, i do'nt need to do anything in order to decrypt the file?
just download and use it?

Comment: @Eli: Yes. I have a test application that stores some json files on S3. To try this, I turned on Server-side encryption and the application worked exactly the same.

Comment: thanx @volkan , but this is very weird since i dont understand how the decryption process is being done..

Comment: @Eli: Encryption and decryption are handled by AWS. Instead of their keys, you can supply your keys: [Use Your own Encryption Keys with S3’s Server-Side Encryption](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-encryption-with-your-keys/) To decrypt you provide the same key and it decrypts and returns the object. In all cases it handles the enc/dec process

Comment: @Eli: Have you just tried to get the object and see if it's clear text or encrypted?

Comment: yes i did, and it works fine, thats why it seems weird, since i did not decrypt it at all, anyway thanx for the replay :)

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean. Sometimes it's hard to follow what's going on when things happen "automagically". But at least it worked :-)